can I get the day duration from date range filter in calculated field in Looker Studio?
I want to create a new field called Total Sales/Day.
I have Total Sales metric already. but the problem is, I dont know how to access the number of days (duration) from date range filter in calculated field formula.
is it possible to get Start Date and End Date from date range filter in Looker Studio?
